# Can't add map service (map cache) to mxd

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, cache, map-service, arcgis-server

When trying to add a map service (in this case a map cache service) to an ArcMap project, I keep getting an error that says:

Could not add specified data object to the map.
Could not connect to the Map Server.

Even though in Catalog I can connect to the service perfectly fine and open it as an mxd project, I can't add it to another project. The goal is to use the map cache as a basemap for editing natural features from an aerial photo. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Using ArcMap 10, ArcServer 10

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that you can preview an ArcGIS Server Map Service in ArcCatalog but cannot add it as a layer in ArcMap?  If so, that sounds odd.  Perhaps check the properties to see if you can get its service URL to copy/paste into Add Data | GIS Servers | Add ArcGIS Server.

Comment: No, it won't preview either. It just shows that it is connected to the server and when I open the map service as an mxd, it works perfectly fine. I just can't preview in catalog or import the service into another map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was fixed by creating an Image Service (as opposed to a map service) and using the image cache as the basis for the service. No issues bringing it into an mxd now.